# Select from mysql where it does not equal row in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a foreach loop and selecting each row that equals that section name. However, I need to also show all results that don't equal any of the section names. Below is the part of my code that is selecting rows where it equals the section name.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sections ORDER BY `order`");
$sectionnames = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $sectionnames[] = $row['sectionname'];
}

foreach ($sectionnames as $sectionname) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faq WHERE section = '$sectionname' ORDER BY `order`");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `faq` WHERE `section` NOT IN (SELECT `sectionname` FROM `sections`)
```

which would select all faq items that do not have a section that shares a name with any sectionname in the sections table? If not then perhaps what juergen d posted is what you need. It's a little unclear exactly what your end goal is, so feel free to clarify and I will update.

Answer (score 2):

I think  it should be,

```
$result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM faq WHERE section NOT IN 
                        (SELECT sectionname FROM sections)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `left join` to get the data in 1 query

```
SELECT * 
FROM sections s
left join faq f on f.section = s.sectionname
ORDER BY s.`order`, f.`order`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT section FROM Faq
    LEFT JOIN Sections 
       ON Faq.section = Sections.sectionname
 WHERE Sections.sectionname IS NULL
```